# Vb.Net - Accessing text in controls on another form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am fairly new to vb.net and would like to be able to access the value (such as .text on a textbox) from another an open form. In my application I open a form from my main form, and when I try to access the text in the controls on the main form I am unable to see the .text value on the control.

I can loop through all controls on the main form just fine, but when I want to see the actual values, all controls are empty. My controls such as text boxes and combo boxes are inside of a tab control and group boxes.

Is there a way to make all .text or values on the open form available from the other open form?

Here is how I am looping through the controls on the main form.

```
Try

    For Each Tp As TabPage In UserData.UserTabControl.TabPages 

    'Name of Tabcontrol is UserTabcontrol

        For Each gbx As GroupBox In Tp.Controls


            For Each ctrl As Control In gbx.Controls

                    If ctrl.Name = "UserName" Then
                        MsgBox(UserData.UserName.Text) 'Messagebox here is empty
                    End If

            Next ctrl

        Next gbx


    Next Tp


    Me.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Thanks in advance. 
Chris

Comment: Can you give us code examples of how you're looping through the controls on your main form?  I suspect that (assuming your main form is called `MyMainForm`) you're looping over `MyMainForm.Controls`, but I'd like to see first :)

Answer (score 1):

From the example you've given you already have access to a reference to your `Control`.  Instead of going back to the `Form` and trying to access that control as a property of the `Form` you could just cast your reference and call its `Text` property directly.

```
If ctrl.Name = "UserName" Then
    MsgBox(DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text) 'Assuming your UserName control is a TextBox
End If
```

Comment: Adrian, I tried that it. The .text is still empty. Just trying different things, I added userdata.show prior to looping through the controls and although it opens the form again, it also showed the value in the msgbox. I am wondering how I can achieve this without opening the main form twice.

Comment: Okay, if you've called `UserData.Close()` prior to trying to get the value from the form then you will fail because it's no longer there to be retrieved.  You'd need to either show your form with `UserData.ShowDialog()` so that closing it as a dialog means it doesn't go away immediately, or use `UserData.Hide()` instead of `UserData.Close()`

Comment: Thank you Adrian for your help, I tried Ron's code and it does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to reference controls on an open form, call it Form1:
First add a Form1 property or variable to the calling form:

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Property f1 As Form1

    ...
    Private Sub DoSomething()
        MsgBox("Here's some text from Form1: " & f1.Textbox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the callee form, set the Form2 property to the form object:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Form2.f1 = Me
       Form2.ShowDialog() ' or Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can then reference all Form1 objects from Form2 using the f1 property.

Comment: Glad to help. Since you are a bit new to SO, I should point out that when a question is satisfactorily answered it is beneficial for you (and the responder) to click the Accept button. You will gain 2 points and improve your acceptance percentage. It will also alert others that time may be better spent moving on to an question not yet accepted question.

Answer (score 0):

By this command, I could change the amount of control in another form.

```
My.Forms.myForm.labelControl.Text = "bela"
```

Please try this :

```
MsgBox(My.Forms.UserData.UserName.Text)
```