# I want to display the content of a text box in two labels on different forms

Tags: vb.net

I am working with five forms:
Sign in
Main
Question
Answers
Score

I want the content of a textbox on the SignIn form to be displayed on a label on the main form and the Score form.

I used this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim frmMain As New Main

    Public Sub btnSignIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSignIn.Click
        frmMain.lblName.Text = "Welcome, " & txtFullName.Text

        Me.Hide()
        frmMain.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

I have a label on the Score form: I want the content of the textbox on the SignIn form to also be displayed there.

Comment: You should look into the concept of _View Models_. In win forms you can just make the label `Public` then you could assign it before you call `ShowDialog()`

Comment: Does [Vb.Net - Accessing text in controls on another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502177/vb-net-accessing-text-in-controls-on-another-form) help?

Comment: The absolute easiest way is to bind Text to application settings. Strictly speaking it's not quite what it was intended for, but it'll work and you can set it up with a few mouse click

Answer (score 1):

Public Class Form1
Dim frmMain As New Main
Public name

```
Public Sub btnSignIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSignIn.Click
```

Name = txtFullName.Text
frmMain.lblName.Text = "Welcome, " & Name

```
    Me.Hide()
    frmMain.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```